# One model not accessible, one is

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have two tiny projects, both use essentially the same setup, one returns a model value one returns the model value as undefined. At this point I am lost as to why these two examples are behaving differently. I checked the failing example, and the model correctly populates

**Successful Behavior**
Partial

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-4 .col-md-offset-4 content-pane no-margin">
    <h4>Input Your Inquiry</h4>
    <form ng-submit="submit(invoice)">
        <div class="control-group">
                  <div class="controls">
                    <div class="input-prepend">
                      <span class="add-on">Invoice Number</span>
                      <input id="who" type="text" class="input-xlarge"     ng-model="invoice.number">
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="control-group">
                  <div class="controls">
                    <div class="input-prepend">
                      <span class="add-on">PO Number</span>
                      <input id="who" type="text" class="input-xlarge" ng-model="invoice.po">
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
        <input type="submit">
    </form>
</div>
<div ng-if="status" class="col-md-4 .col-md-offset-4 content-pane no-margin">
    <h4>Invoice Status</h4>
    <div>{{status}}</div>
</div>
</div>
```

App.js

```
app.config(function($routeProvider){

    $routeProvider
        .when('/',
            {
                templateUrl: 'app/partials/inquiry-input-form.html',
                controller: 'MainCtrl'
            })
        .otherwise(
            {
            templateUrl: 'app/partials/404.html'
            })
});

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope,formsResults) {
    $scope.submit = function() {
        var invoiceNum = $scope.invoice.number;
        var po = $scope.invoice.po;
        formsResults.getInvoiceStatus(po,invoiceNum).success(function(data) {
            var status = data.records;

            if (angular.isUndefined(status)) {
                $scope.status = 'Pending Reciept or Entry';
            } else {
                $scope.status = status[0].field_124208[0];
            }
        });
    };
});

app.factory('formsResults', function($http) {............
```

**Returning Model as undefined in controller**
Partial

```
<tabset>
    <tab active=workspace.active>
        <tab-heading>
            Search All Fields
        </tab-heading>
        <div>
        <br /><br />
            <form class="form-horizontal" ng-submit="submitAll(searches)">

                <div class="form-group">
                  <div class="col-md-4">
                  <input id="textinput" name="textinput" type="text" class="form-control input-md" ng-model="searches.term">
                  <span class="help-block">Enter the term you wish to search on.</span>  
                  {{searches.term}}
                  </div>
                </div>

                <!-- Button -->
                <div class="form-group">
                  <div class="col-md-4">

                    <button id="singlebutton" name="singlebutton" class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Search</button>
                  </div>
                </div>

            </form>     
        </div>
    </tab>
    <tab>
        <tab-heading>
            Search By Field
        </tab-heading>
        <div>
        <br /><br />
            <form class="form-horizontal" ng-submit="submitSpecific(search)">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <div class="col-md-4">
                    <select id="selectbasic" name="selectbasic" class="form-control">

                      <option value="4">Country</option>
                    </select>
                    <span class="help-block">Enter the field you wish to search on.</span>  
                  </div>
                </div>

                <!-- Text input-->
                <div class="form-group">
                  <div class="col-md-4">
                  <input id="textinput" name="textinput" type="text" class="form-control input-md">
                  <span class="help-block">Enter the term you wish to search on.</span>  
                  </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                  <div class="col-md-4">

                    <button id="singlebutton" name="singlebutton" class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Search</button>
                  </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </tab>
</tabset>
```

App.js

```
var app = angular.module ('app',['ngRoute','ngSanitize','ui.bootstrap','dialogs.controllers','dialogs']);

app.config(function($routeProvider){
    //http://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_07
    $routeProvider
        .when('/',
            {
                templateUrl: 'app/partials/home_tpl.html',
                controller: 'HomeCtrl'
            })
        .when('/search',
            {
                templateUrl: 'app/partials/search-form.html',
                controller: 'SearchCtrl'
            })
        .when('/add-sop',
            {
                templateUrl: 'app/partials/support-process.html',
                controller: 'EditSOPCtrl'
            })
        .otherwise(
            {
            redirectTo: '/'
            })
});

app.controller('HomeCtrl', function($scope) {

});

app.controller('SearchCtrl', function($scope,formsSopSearchCriteria) {

    $scope.submitAll = function() {
        var searchTerm = $scope.searches.term;
        console.log(searchTerm);
        var searchPackage={
                "offset":0,
                "limit":0,
                "fields":["record_id","dt_created","created_by","dt_updated","updated_by",149654,149655,149692],
                "filters":{"and":[{"field_id":"149655","operator":"contains","value":searchTerm}]},
                "sort":{}
        };
        searchPackage=JSON.stringify(searchPackage);
        $scope.searchPackage = searchPackage;

        formsSopSearchCriteria.getMatches(searchPackage).success(function(data) {
            $scope.sopRecords = data.records;
        });
    };

    $scope.submitSpecific = function() {

        var searchPackage = ""
        searchPackage=JSON.stringify(searchPackage);
        $scope.searchPackage = searchPackage;

        formsSopSearchCriteria.getMatches(searchPackage).success(function(data) {
            $scope.sopRecords = data.records;
        });
    };

});


app.factory('formsSopSearchCriteria',function($http) {........
```

Any ideas? My understanding is that it as an issue of scope. But in the failing example, the partial I provide is mapped to the SearchCtrl in the routeProvider. As a result the model should be available in the controller, just like the example that is working. I suspect I must be missing something, but I am not clear what I am missing.

Comment: Let me put it this way. In the working examples, invoice is passed by submit fine, and I use child values of that. In what looks to me like identical syntax, searches cannot either be set or passed from the controller for the partial defined by routeProvider. I cannot see how the two are different.  I know this seems like an incredibly beginner question, but I'm lost.

Comment: Writing an answer in a few minutes.

Comment: Did I need to initialize searches? I didn't do that in the working example.

Comment: Yes. Do you still want me to post an explanation?

Comment: Sure, I'd be happy to mark it as the answer. Any idea why the working example works when I don't initialize invoice, then? Seems like that example should not be functioning, given our comments here.

Comment: Yes, I will explain why in my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create `$scope.searches` as an empty object on initialization:

```
app.controller('SearchCtrl', function($scope,formsSopSearchCriteria) {

  $scope.searches = {};
```

Or for clarity:

```
$scope.searches =
{
  term: ''
};
```

If you don't, it will not be created until the first input is entered (I believe it is the `$parse` service that the `ng-model` directive uses that creates the searches object in this case).

The problem is that the object might not be created in the scope you want it to.

The reason it works in the first case is because there are no child scopes, so the `invoice` object is created in the controller scope.

In the second case there is one or many child scopes (probably from the tabs, I haven't dug any deeper into it), so the `searches` object is created in one of those instead.

Due to how prototypical inheritance works in Javascript, if you predefine the objects in the controllers' scopes, the properties will be created correctly.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the additional potential scope issues. I'll certainly remember to always initialize, now.